# How to trigger a Gitlab CI job on update of Google Sheet or respective file in Google Drive

Tags: google-sheets, gitlab, google-drive-api, gitlab-ci

I have a Gitlab CI scheduled job which regularly downloads a Google Sheet and performs certain tasks upon changes in the sheet.

Is there a way to automatically trigger a Gitlab CI job if a Google Sheet or the respective file in Google Drive is getting updated?

Answer (score 1):

On the Gitlab side you are looking for the `pipeline triggers`. They can be found under project *Settings > Ci/CD*.

On the Google side have a look at `Extensions > AppScript` and its triggers.